# pass the reference of this class inside it's constructor to a vector of pointers C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, vector, entity

Okay so i have a pointer vector of type 'Entity', and what i want to do is, when a new Entity type class gets constructed it gets pushed back to the vector of Entities, in C# this would be possible by passing 'this' as a parameter, in C++ it gives no error, but when i test it, the vector doesn't point to the newly contructed Entity !

Here is some code:

'Public.h' and 'Public.cpp' handle the public variables and functions, here is the pointer vector and pointer variable

```
vector <Entity*> AllEntities;
Entity* lastEntity;
```

And here is the constructor of the class 'Entity'

'Entity.cpp':

```
#include "Public.h"
#include "Entity.h"

// constructor
    Entity::Entity(string name, string tag)
    {
        ID = GetCounter();
        this->Name = UniqueName(name);
        this->Tag = UniqueTag(tag);
        AllEntities.push_back(this); // it doesn't give any errors
        lastEntity = this; // because i thought it was a problem with the vector i tried the same with a variable, but it doesn't work too
    }

// Function that prints the name, tag, and id.

void Entity::PrintAll(){
    cout << "NAME: \"" << Entity::Name << "\" TAG: \"" << Entity::Tag << "\" ID: \"" << Entity::ID << "\"" << endl;
}
```

// other code

'Entity.h' doesn't do much, it only handles the declaration(or definition, not sure how its called) of variables and functions like Name, Tag, and ID !

and here is my 'Main.cpp':

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML\System.hpp"
#include "Public.h"
#include "DisplayText.h"
#include "SaySomething.h"
// note that i'm including 'Entity.h' through 'Public.h' with Include Guards so i won't get any linker errors !

int main()
{
// sfml stuff !
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");

    Entity ent1 = Entity("ent1");

    ent1.PrintAll();

    AllEntities.at(0)->PrintAll();

    lastEntity->PrintAll();
```

// other code

> Entity ent1 = Entity("ent1");

here i create a new entity, with the name "ent1", and it automatically gives it the tag "Entity0" and the ID "0" because its the first entity !

> ent1.PrintAll();

This works correctly, it prints out the name("ent1"), tag and ID of this Entity !

> AllEntities.at(0)->PrintAll();

This basically calls the function 'PrintAll' from the first Entity(which in this case is 'ent1'), and its supposed to print the same text as this: 'ent1.PrintAll()' but it does not, it prints:
    (Name: "" with Tag: "" and ID: ""), i thought i was not using the vector correctly but as shown below it doesn't work with pointers too:

> lastEntity->PrintAll();

This doesn't work !

I'm not sure what the problem is, and how to fix it, firstly i thought maybe something about the variables: 'Name' and 'Tag' and 'ID' doesn't work, but the problem is that the vector doesn't point to the variable, i've tried with lots of different functions, not only with printing name, but it doesn't 'track' the Entity that was created !

Comment: This doesn't really make sense that it would compile. Is lastEntity a member variable of Entity? What about AllEntities? Show us you're "entity.h"

Comment: i did not use the entire code, because the other code doesn't matter for my specific question ! ouh and i forgot to add lastEntity, i will edit it

Comment: What I'm asking is, where are those two variables defined. Are they global variables, or are they declared within your class, like 'class Entity { ... vector <Entity*> AllEntities;
Entity* lastEntity; ...   }'

Comment: obviously global.

Comment: do me a favor. Print the `this` pointer inside the function. Print the `lastentiry` pointer.  Are they identical ?

Comment: that was very smart of you, i basically printed the variables Name, Tag, and ID inside the contructor, once from this->Name, Tag etc, and the second time from: lastEntity->Name, Tag etc.and yes they print the same thing

Comment: @Drinkadriu are the addresses identical ?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. The constructor for `Entity` you've shown wouldn't even get called with the example code you posted.

Comment: @KostasRim Yes, so the value: (this) = (lastEntity), but the address of lastEntity is different, but that is supposed to happen.

Comment: if `cout << this << endl;` == `cout << lastEntity << endl;` then everything should work fine. It seems very stange.  Could you please also try : `Entity ent1("ent1")` instead of `Entity ent1 = Entity("ent1");` ?

Comment: @KostasRim something pretty weird happend.. ok so when i print (this, and lastEntity) from the constructor they have the same address, but when i print the reference of the variable ent1 its not the same as lastEntity and this(from the constructor), i have no idea why though

Comment: OMG IT worked, THANK YOU so much @KostasRim, seriously i've been trying to solve this problem for days, if you could make it an answer so others can learn too from this :D, Entity ent1("ent1") -> worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Entity ent1 = Entity("ent1");` to `Entity ent1("ent1")`. This will properly construct your object.

Comment: can you please explain a little why do i have to do that ?

Comment: @Drinkadriu yes the statement `Entity("ent1")` creates a temporary object of type `Entity` which is then copied (using the `copy constructor` which you have NOT defined). You end up with a bad constructed object. The `Entity ent1("ent1")` properly calls the constructor.

Comment: @Drinkadriu: What happens if you make 2 entities and try to print both of them? I fear that it will not work correctly. Post a [mcve] as I requested.

Comment: @AndyG it will work if the objects are created properly. I am pretty sure that my guess is correct. Unfortunately, we can't be 100% sure without knowing all the class details.

Comment: @Kostas: Well... maybe with an old compiler, or a new one with copy elision explicitly turned off.

Comment: @KostasRim: OP accesses name and id with the "::" operator, not the `.` operator, so they are likely `static`, and hence he'll get bad output for 2.

Comment: KostasRim is right, i tried it and it works amazingly with a lot of entities !, now i have finally completed my ECS, going to post it in GitHub in the next couple of days, when i do i will let you guys know !

Comment: @Drinkadriu: Create 2 `Entity` objects. Then call `AllEntities.at(0)->PrintAll();` Then call `AllEntities.at(1)->PrintAll();`

Comment: @AndyG Yes, you are right Andy they are probably static. Unfortunately, without the class details I can't be sure, neither do you. But keep in mind that operator `::` can be used even if the members are not static. If `::` is used for non-static variables it prompts to class members. P.S again I am making a guess that he misplaced the `::`.

Comment: @KostasRim: "If :: is used for non-static variables it prompts to class members" I'm not sure I follow what you mean. It's a compiler error if the rhs is non-static class member variable.

Comment: @AndyG if for example there is a non static `private` integer `j` inside the class and on a `print` function you write `cout << class_name::j << endl;` it will print the value `j` even if j is not static. Inside a class all members are prefixed with `class_name::` even if you don't explicitly write them.

Comment: @KostasRim: Oh I follow! My mistake. The Print function is a member function, too, so it's okay. Thank you.

Comment: @AndyG no problem but to an extent you were right. I guessed that his variables were not `static`, if they were my answer would be wrong.

Comment: @KostasRim AndyG guys i created a git repository for my project, please forgive the bad organization of the repository but unfortunaly i do not know how to properly use github, here is the link:https://github.com/drinkadriu/DrInK-ECS

Comment: @AndyG i made a git repository